# I am not able to upload files in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to upload files in selenium webdriver ....
 **My code is here**: : driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]")).SendKeys ("E:/QA/upload test pictures/dreamstime_xl_11004542-Copy.jpg");

**I am getting error ** : System.InvalidOperationException: 'unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: Hello, user9990064.
Post your code to better verify the source of the problem.

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]")).SendKeys ("E:/QA/upload test pictures/dreamstime_xl_11004542-Copy.jpg");

Comment: From the error message it seems that selenium could not find the element through xpath. Attempts to locate the element by ID or ClassName, for example.

Comment: yeah I have tried  it by id but it doesn't work                                                driver.FindElement(By.Id("html5_1cgs3jb961549lorg7t86n1ir04_container")).SendKeys ("E:/QA/upload test pictures/dreamstime_xl_11004542-Copy.jpg");.....................Gives me error OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Post the HTML code of the page here, or submit the link to the site you are trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't .SendKeys() to a div element. Look for the `<input>` tag instead.

Comment: yeah I have used id instead of xpath